# Is it possible for a Bayes estimator to be independent of the sample?

Tags: self-study

I am trying to derive the Bayes estimator. Without getting into the nuts and bolts of the question, basically I have an indicator loss function of the form

$$L(\delta , \theta) = \mathbb{1}\{A\}$$

For an event $A$. I found that $EL(\delta,\theta |X)$ is minimized for almost all $X$ when $\delta$ is a function solely of the hyperparameters of $\theta$'s prior distribution. A theorem in my textbook then implies that such a $\delta$ is the bayes estimator of $\theta$.

On the one hand this seems ridiculous, but then again I figure such a result might be correct since we have a somewhat strange loss function.

I can go into the details of the problem if needed.

---

To clarify. We have the posterior distribution $\theta | X$ as being a truncated $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ distribution truncated below at $\max_i X_i$. I want to derive the Bayes estimator under the loss function

$$L_\epsilon (\theta, \delta) = 1 - 1 \{ \delta - \epsilon \leq \theta \leq \delta + \epsilon \}$$

To find the $\delta$ that minimizes this, clearly it is equivalent to find the $\delta$ that maximizes

$$E 1 \{ \delta - \epsilon \leq \theta \leq \delta + \epsilon \}$$

There is also a theorem in my textbook that says it is enough to show that $\delta$ minimizes $E[L(\theta, \delta)|X]$ for almost all $X$ for it to be a Bayes estimator. So to find the Bayes estimator I tried to find the $\delta$ that maximizes

$$E [1 \{ \delta - \epsilon \leq \theta \leq \delta + \epsilon \}|X] = P(\delta - \epsilon \leq \theta \leq \delta + \epsilon | X)$$

Since we know the posterior distribution of $\theta$ is truncated normal we can work with this probability. From here I used the CDF of the truncated normal distribution $F$ given on the Wikipedia page to find the $\delta$ that minimizes

$$F(\delta + \epsilon) - F(\delta - \epsilon)$$

and using $$\frac{d\Phi (f(\delta))}{d\delta} = f'(\delta) \phi(f(\delta))$$ I found was that this is maximized when

$$\delta = \mu$$

which does not depend on $X$ at all. So I'm pretty sure I'm making a stupid mistake, or have misunderstood how to find Bayes estimators.

Comment: This question is not precise enough, how is $A$ connected with $\delta$ and $\theta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one considers the loss function 
$$L(\delta , \theta) = \mathbb{1}_{|\theta-\delta|>\epsilon}$$ the Bayes estimator $\delta^*(\cdot)$ is obtained as solving$$\arg\min_\delta\mathbb{E}[L(\delta , \theta) | x]$$for every $x$. Now
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[L(\delta , \theta) | x] &= \int L(\delta , \theta)\pi(\theta | x)\,\text{d}x\\
&= \int \mathbb{1}_{|\theta-\delta|>\epsilon}\,\text{d}x\\
&= \mathbb{P}(|\theta-\delta|>\epsilon)\\
&= 1-\pi([\delta-\epsilon,\delta+\epsilon] | x)
\end{align*}
One thus wants to maximise the coverage of $[\delta-\epsilon,\delta+\epsilon]$ under the posterior distribution. This amounts to finding the location $\delta$ of the center of an interval of length $2\epsilon$ with the largest coverage. A graphic illustration is to imagine a stick of length $2\epsilon$ that is moved up under the graph of $\pi(\cdot|x)$ until it cannot move higher. **It obviously depends on $\pi(\cdot)$ and on $f(x|\theta)$.**

Note that differentiating $\pi([\delta-\epsilon,\delta+\epsilon] | x)$ in $\delta$ leads to$$\pi(\delta-\epsilon)=\pi(\delta+\epsilon)$$meaning that the resulting interval is an HPD region if the posterior is unimodal and monotone on each side of the posterior mode (MAP). **It is only when the posterior is symmetric that $\delta^*$ is the MAP.** Note also that when the posterior support is truncated, as in the truncated Normal example, the solution is an HPD but does not necessarily satisfy the equation$$\pi(\delta-\epsilon)=\pi(\delta+\epsilon)$$. For instance, if the posterior is the Normal distribution $\text{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ truncated below $\max x_i>\mu$, $\delta^*$ will be equal to $\max x_i+\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks Xi'an, it is good to know the formal reasoning. I will have a think about how to deal with the truncation in order to maximize the coverage. I think my mistake before is assuming that $\mu$ is in the support of the posterior? when there's no guarantee that is the case.

Comment: After working through it I found the solution is a lot closer to what I was expecting. Thanks again